# Random sample of a random sample from a population: Also a random sample?

Tags: probability, sampling, resampling

From population P we draw an adequately sized random sample S1. From the sample S1 we draw an adequately sized random sample S2 (with replacement).

Are the distributional characteristics of S2 unbiased estimators of those of P (and S1)?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is “Is a simple random sample with replacement of size n2 from an initial random sample with replacement of size n1 (with n1 > n2), equivalent to a simple random sample with replacement of size n2?”, then the answer is no.

However, a simple random sample without replacement of size n2 from an initial random sample with replacement of size n1 (with n1 > n2) is equivalent to a simple random sample with replacement of size n2.

Here is some R code showing how the frequencies of selection differs between the three scenarios using 1,000,000 simulated samples.

```
# Define a small population of values
  n <- 5
  population <- c(1:n)

# Take random samples of size 2 with replacement
# and determine frequency of observations
  f2 = matrix(rep(0,n*n),nrow=n)
  nsim <- 1000000
  for (i in 1:nsim) {
      s2 <- sample(population,2,replace=TRUE)
      f2[s2[1],s2[2]] <- f2[s2[1],s2[2]] + 1
  }
  f2 <- f2/nsim

# Take random sample of size 4 with replacement.
# Then a random sample of size 2 with replacement
# and determine the frequency of observations
  f2a = matrix(rep(0,n*n),nrow=n)
  for (i in 1:nsim) {
      s4 <- sample(population,4,replace=TRUE)
      s2a <- sample(s4,2,replace=TRUE)
      f2a[s2a[1],s2a[2]] <- f2a[s2a[1],s2a[2]] + 1
  }
  f2a <- f2a/nsim

# Take random sample of size 4 with replacement.
# Then a random sample of size 2 without replacement
# and determine the frequency of observations
  f2b <- matrix(rep(0,n*n),nrow=n)
  for (i in 1:nsim) {
      s4 <- sample(population,4,replace=TRUE)
      s2b <- sample(s4,2,replace=FALSE)
      f2b[s2b[1],s2b[2]] <- f2b[s2b[1],s2b[2]] + 1
  }
  f2b <- f2b/nsim

# Random sample of size 2 with replacement
  f2

  # Random sample of size 2 with replacement from
  # an initial sample of size 4 with replacement
  f2a

  # Random sample of size 2 without replacement from
  # an initial sample of size 4 with replacement
  f2b
```

with output

```
>   # Random sample of size 2 with replacement
>   f2
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 0.039960 0.040228 0.040084 0.040095 0.039917
[2,] 0.040035 0.040122 0.039941 0.040082 0.040146
[3,] 0.040064 0.039668 0.040266 0.040142 0.039969
[4,] 0.039866 0.039622 0.040340 0.039706 0.039942
[5,] 0.040235 0.039976 0.040063 0.039919 0.039612
> 
>   # Random sample of size 2 with replacement from
>   # an initial sample of size 4 with replacement
>   f2a
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 0.079537 0.030008 0.029914 0.029987 0.030036
[2,] 0.029898 0.079462 0.030027 0.029861 0.030338
[3,] 0.029627 0.030162 0.079729 0.030180 0.030073
[4,] 0.030162 0.030234 0.029918 0.079717 0.030011
[5,] 0.030236 0.030178 0.030225 0.030064 0.080416
> 
>   # Random sample of size 2 without replacement from
>   # an initial sample of size 4 with replacement
>   f2b
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 0.040017 0.040166 0.040213 0.039929 0.040011
[2,] 0.039767 0.039994 0.040593 0.039854 0.040028
[3,] 0.039735 0.039960 0.039909 0.039812 0.040133
[4,] 0.040184 0.039688 0.039886 0.039747 0.040264
[5,] 0.039842 0.040150 0.039965 0.040219 0.039934
```

The relative frequencies of the potential samples show that when the second sample of size n2 is taken with replacement, one does not obtain the same relative frequencies as if one initially takes samples of size n2 with replacement.