# Formal proof that a subsample of a random sample is representative

Tags: sample, randomness

There are two questions asking about the random nature of a subsample ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17626/subsample-of-a-random-sample-random-sample) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160041/random-sample-of-a-random-sample-from-a-population-also-a-random-sample?rq=1)). However, they do not provide a formal proof of the result. I am looking for a proof to support my selection mechanism.

The specific problem is:

Say I have a random sample of size $M$, drawn from a given population. One of the dimensions of that population is, for example, gender. Now, from the above sample, I selects only those individuals who are female, obtaining a subsample of size $N$ (naturally, $N<M$). The question is: **is that subsample representative of the population of females?**

Comment: If everybody in the population has equal probability $p$ of being in your full sample, then every female in the population has equal probability $p$ of being in your subsample.

Comment: I refer to that question. As you can see, there is no formal proof there. @josliber, Is that it? What about the (relative) size of the subsample?

Comment: @josliber, why not write that up as an official answer?